# Куда делись остальные комментарии в очереди проверок?

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

Куда делись остальные комментарии в очереди проверок ?:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И все?

Comment: Вероятно, дело в том, что «этот ответ был размещён довольно давно»